# Drupal 6 multisite, shared theme issue

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal site currently running 1 site. The site used a theme located in /themes  (meaning the themes folder in not in the sites folder).

So I'm trying to add another site that will use the same database, and take the current theme and change it a bit. so I copied the theme folder to : /sites/newsite.com/themes/ . i changed the name of  the theme in the info file.

But you know what happened? The old site now uses the theme in: " /sites/newsite.com/themes/ "! how is that possible? It changed automatically.....

really weird....

by the way, the new site is also in the new theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You said you changed the name of the theme in the .info file, for the new site.  Did you also change the name of the directory for the new theme?